# StackView with a MapView not working properly on initial load

Tags: ios, autolayout, mapkit, scrollview, uistackview

Quick update, as I see a lot of interest in this now that iOS 10 is live. I ultimately opened a TSI and Apple responded back today indicating that I should open a bug for this. They didn't provide any further info or suggestions for workarounds, and the implication is that there is something wrong here.

In the meantime, I'm still digging for a workaround.  I pulled my entire layout out of the StackView and replaced with autolayout constraints, only to experience the same issue. The problem may be with the MapView.

---

I have an issue where placing a few labels and a MapView in a vertical StackView. This view is not behaving consistently with iOS 10 / Xc8.

On the 6/S simulator, it renders properly. On the SE, the `MapView` actually appears larger than it did on the 6, and it covers up the labels. That resolves after a rotation (and it appears fine in the Storyboard preview)

I've demonstrated the behavior with an extremely simple project. It contains a Storyboard view with one vertical StackView that looks like this:

[image]

The StackView uses the Fill alignment and Fill distribution. There is no spacing.

Each label has a content hugging priority of 251 and compression resistance of 750.

The `MapView` has content hugging of 250 and compression of 750.

I've tried playing around with those numbers, but it never worked. In theory, the `MapView` has the lowest hugging priority so it should use up all extra space with the Fill distribution.

Instead, this is what I see (on the SE sim)

[image: bottom two labels covered by the MapView]

If I rotate the device and back - it looks fine. So it seems like there is some timing issue with the layout. However, I'm doing nothing in code here - the text of the labels is hardcoded in the `storyboard`. I don't do anything in code.

As mentioned, it looks fine on the iPhone6. It also looks fine if I arbitrarily tweak the heights of the labels.  I noticed when the labels were all the same `fontsize` especially, it was fine. So I wonder if it's using the initial label's `fontsize` for calculating the intrinsic `contentsize` or something strange like that.

The iPad Air sim also has issues. In fact, the entire display is covered by the map initially, and I don't see the labels at all (until rotating).

I am not sure if `ScrollViews` are supposed to play nicely with `StackViews`.  That said, I did try pulling the `MapView` out of there and pinning it below the `StackView` with `autolayout`. Surprisingly, I had the same end results.

Final note—I didn't test this with the sample project, but in my original project (exhibiting the same behavior) this occurred in Xcode 8 but not in Xcode 7.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue :(

Comment: have you added any constraint on labels or MapView in stackView ?

Comment: and also what is Distribution type you set for stackView?

Comment: Tried this before noticing it was originally created two years ago, ha! Looks like it's no longer an issue under Xcode 9.